# outcome variable as argument in regression function

Tags: r, function, arguments, dplyr

I have a datasetup function which currently has 2 arguments: testData and ID1. I want to include outcome variable as an argument.

Suppose outcomevar=c(y1,y2,y3) then the function should create the lagged and differenced variable of my outcome variable.

```
preparedata<-function(testData,ID1,outcomevar){
#Order temp data by firm and date
            testData <- testData[order(testData$firm,testData$date),]
#Create lagged outcomevar for each firm
            testData <- ddply(testData, .(firm), transform,
            ly1 = c( NA, y1[-length(y1)] ) )
#Create differenced variable
            testData$dy1<-(testData$y1-testData$ly1)
}
```

where the "l" and "d" in front of y1 stand for lagged and differenced. 
Depending How can I include the outcome variable? 
Thanks 
T

Comment: outcomevar could be y1, y2 or y3. So it's a vector of 3 and the function will create the lagged variable for the selected y, e.g. preparedata<-function(testData,ID1=1,outcomevar=y1) will prepare the data for ID 1 and create the lagged variable for y1. The prepare data function does other simple steps which are excluded since irrelevant.

Comment: I could do this with an if statement, but i will need to copy a large section of the code 3 times. I don't want that.

Comment: temp is mydata. It contains all outcomevars. Please see my updated post. temp=testData in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using data tables:

```
# create sample dataset
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(firm=rep(LETTERS[1:5],each=10),
                 date=as.Date("2014-01-01")+1:10,
                 y1=sample(1:100,50),y2=sample(1:100,50),y3=sample(1:100,50))


preparedata<-function(testData,ID1,outcomevar){
  require(data.table)
  DT <- as.data.table(testData)
  setkey(DT,firm,date)
  DT[,lag  := c(NA,unlist(.SD)[-.N]),  by=firm, .SDcols=outcomevar]
  DT[,diff := c(NA,diff(unlist(.SD))), by=firm, .SDcols=outcomevar]
  setnames(DT,c("lag","diff"),paste0(c("l","d"),outcomevar))
  return(DT)
}

result <- preparedata(df,1,outcomevar="y1")
head(result)
#    firm       date y1 y2 y3 ly1 dy1
# 1:    A 2014-01-02 27 48 66  NA  NA
# 2:    A 2014-01-03 37 86 35  27  10
# 3:    A 2014-01-04 57 43 27  37  20
# 4:    A 2014-01-05 89 24 97  57  32
# 5:    A 2014-01-06 20  7 61  89 -69
# 6:    A 2014-01-07 86 10 21  20  66
```

This assumes you pass the *name* of the column containing the "outcomevar", not the column itself.

You should read the documentation on data tables (`?data.table`), but in brief this code converts the input data frame to a data table, orders the data table (using `setkey(...)`), and adds two new columns by reference: `lag` and `diff`. `.SD` is a special variable in the data table framework which is an alias for "the subset of the original DT containing the rows specified in `by=...`". You can specify which columns to include using `.SDcols=...`. The `diff(...)` function calculates lagged differences, which is the same thing you were doing. Finally, we rename the columns `lag` and `diff` to, e.g. `ly1` and `dy1`.

Comment: That works great! Thank you! Is there anyway that i can amend this to also create the diff(lag(outcomevar)) as a third line?

Comment: I was previously doing this using the explicit name of the outcomevar:testData <- ddply( 
  testData, .(firm), transform, dloutcome = c( NA, loutcome[-length(loutcome)] ) )

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of a function that relies more heavily on your example:

```
 preparedata<-function(testData,outcomevar){
   require(plyr)
   testData <- testData[order(testData$firm,testData$date),]
   testData$tmp.var <- with(testData, eval(parse(text=outcomevar)))
   testData <- ddply(testData, .(firm), transform, 
                     lvar = c( NA, tmp.var[-length(tmp.var)]))
   testData$tmp.var <- NULL
   testData <- within(testData, assign(paste("d", outcomevar, sep=""),
                                       testData[,outcomevar]-testData$lvar))
   colnames(testData)[grep("lvar", colnames(testData))] <- paste("l", outcomevar, sep="")
   return(testData)
 }
```

Using the `df` defined in jihoward's answer, we get

```
 > head(preparedata(df,"y1"))

   firm       date y1 y2 y3 lvar dy1
 1    A 2014-01-02 27 48 66   NA  NA
 2    A 2014-01-03 37 86 35   27  10
 3    A 2014-01-04 57 43 27   37  20
 4    A 2014-01-05 89 24 97   57  32
 5    A 2014-01-06 20  7 61   89 -69
 6    A 2014-01-07 86 10 21   20  66
```

This function returns a dataframe where `ly1` is the lagged variable, and `dy1` is the differenced variable that was specified with the second argument `outcomevar`. Note that in this function, you pass the **name** (i.e. a character) to the function. That is, do not write `y1`, but `"y1"` when you call the function.

Comment: I got an error after trying this. Could you recheck the syntax? Error in head(preparedata(df, "y1")) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'head': Error in head(preparedata(df, "y1")) : object 'outcomevar' not found

Comment: Working great now! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could process all outcome variables simultaneously by first gathering them into a key-value column pair:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  firm = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 10),
  date = as.Date("2014-01-01") + 1:10,
  y1 = sample(100, 50),
  y2 = sample(100, 50),
  y3 = sample(100, 50)
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather(key, value, y1:y3) %>%
  group_by(firm, key) %>%
  mutate(lag = lag(value), diff = lag - value)
#> Source: local data frame [150 x 6]
#> Groups: firm, key
#> 
#>    firm       date key value lag diff
#> 1     A 2014-01-02  y1    27  NA   NA
#> 2     A 2014-01-03  y1    37  27  -10
#> 3     A 2014-01-04  y1    57  37  -20
#> 4     A 2014-01-05  y1    89  57  -32
#> 5     A 2014-01-06  y1    20  89   69
#> 6     A 2014-01-07  y1    86  20  -66
#> 7     A 2014-01-08  y1    97  86  -11
#> 8     A 2014-01-09  y1    62  97   35
#> 9     A 2014-01-10  y1    58  62    4
#> 10    A 2014-01-11  y1     6  58   52
#> ..  ...        ... ...   ... ...  ...
```